# Uninstalling Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: uninstall, format

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.10 from an external drive which I'm using as my main drive. I need to format the drive to install Windows 7, but this laptop doesn't have a cd drive.

I made a bootable usb with windows 7 and wasn't able to install because this version doesn't have the disc repair options and the installation menu won't let me format the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try Linux boot repair disc, it can wipe off the disk partition.
or make another bootable usb with windows version 8 or higher and try to clean install the windows i.e. by formating the hdd partition.

Comment: How do i use boot repair? I can use cd's